# cant run linux mint on usb stick (no access to hard drive currently) kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init exitcode=0x00000009

Tags: usb-drive, laptop, kernel-panic

I  have swapped out the cpu for another one though, it’s a sony vaio vpcf11s1e with gt 330m, i3 350qm and 8 gbs of ddr3 ram.

I had to swap out the i7 720qm for an i3 350m what was laying around i7 was broken and the gpu or screen is broken as the colors are all messed up, but it still displays and I can’t try on a different screen until I have an os installed.

Is there anyway i can get it to boot into Linux?

Comment: The fact that it booted the kernel and was trying to start userspace is encouraging. I don't know mint, but on general principals I would interrupt the boot at the grub menu stage. If there is a "recovery" option available at that point I would try it. Next I would again interrupt it at the grub menu stage, use "e" to edit the command. First I would try adding " single" onto the end of the command. The next thing to try is adding " init=/bin/sh".

Comment: how do i interrupt a boot and what is the grub menu stage, have never used linux before

Comment: GRUB is the normal bootloader. It frequently gives you a list of options for a few seconds. You can interrupt the countdown by pressing any key on the keyboard. If there isn't a menu shown then holding down the right shift key whilst booting might make it appear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.